# Aligning Text Center of Div

Tags: css

Hello a small problem here that im struggling to fix. Tried vertical-align with no joy and have ran out of ideas.

You can see why frontpage blocks [HERE](http://onlinebanter.com/)

The title below the picture is sitting towards the top of that area when the title only takes up one line. I was hoping to make it appear in the middle of that area between the picture and the group title below. Could anyone suggest anything?

Thanks

```
    ul.views-fluid-grid-items-center li.views-fluid-grid-item {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
        position: relative;
    }

    li.views-fluid-grid-item .views-field-title {
        padding: 0 4px;
    }
```

Comment: What title and what picture.

Comment: Take a look a this [link showing how to vertically center multi lined text](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I marked, all the black part in your website are fixed in height, just use `display: table-cell` along with `vertical-align: middle` and you are good to go

```
li.views-fluid-grid-item .views-field-title a {
    color: #AAAAAA;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 40px; /* Fix appropriate height here */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: One-line text isn't centered aligned.
Add `inline-block` one the `.field-content` and a `text-align:center` on the parent.

Comment: a brilliant chaps thanks for all your help. ill go read up and get back in a sec. tx

Answer (score 1):

You could add `line-height: 37px;` to `li.views-fluid-grid-item .views-field-title a`

but then you would have to cut off the text from going onto two lines..

Edit: I'll leave this on here for reference but I prefer Mr. Alien's answer

Comment: What if text is not in a single line?

Comment: Seems to be ok on single and double lines Mr Alien thanks to yourself. Ive got the title length limited and so far so good. Ah i see your speaking to Danny Mr A. Thanks too Danny. Thanks to soyuka. Ive added the code too and that works great. also i will go have a read of your link. Im picking css up slowly. Only taken me 7 years.